concatenate data from column year when GROUP BY on Column Amount (MySQL)
I have a table from which I generate a view Grouping By Year and summing the amounts, and I wonder if I could somehow include a "string sum" or "string concatenation" of the aggregated dates or months.
Example: this is the base table
ID | date | year | month | amount

This is the actual view
ID | year | sum(amount)

what I am looking for is an additional field with concatenates the months to 03,05,11 (for example or to something similar), if a year aggregates data from march, may and november
ID | year | sum(amount) | list_of_months

Is that possible or do I have to create helping views to aggregate that?
Edit: I was able to answer myself: Group_concat to the help as shown in the answer below

Please run show create table tableName and add the output on the question in text format. Add some data examples and expected result

Sorry I forgot to format the table-headers and it was badly legible.
Nevertheless the example is so simple that with minor abstract thinking it should be possible. Also I was able to answer myself: I was looking for GROUP_CONCAT ('column' SEPARATOR ',') AS 'list_of_months'

Group_Concat to the help

    SELECT 
    ...
    year,
    SUM(`amount`) AS `sum(amount)`,
    GROUP_CONCAT(`month` SEPARATOR ',') AS `list_of_months`
    ...
    FROM ...
    WHERE ...
    GROUP BY 'year'


